# 1 state, 2 different event for 2 modal

Tags: reactjs

I would like to pass 1 state(open) to different modal(3) all related to a different event

```
if(event1){
 state=true
 return <Component1 open="state">
}
//same code
if(event2){...}
// same code
if(event3){...}
```

I already tried

create each event in each component
but when I combine

```
<Component1 />
<Component2 />
<component3 />
```

only the event from Component1 is working and not the other.
only if I comment event from Component1 the second will work and the same thing with the next one

I tried to send as props

```
<Component1 open={this.state.open} />
<Component2 open={this.state.open} />
<component3 open={this.state.open} />
```

still, not a good solution cos does not matter which event is activited state Component1 will always open first if I comment event from Component1 the second will the shitty idea

I tried to put a switch into the "return" but react do not let any state changement into the "return"

```
class Index extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
 this.state = {
  open = false
 }
}

handleClose = () => {
 this.setState({
   open: false
  })
}

handleOpen = () => {
  this.setState({
    open: true
  })
}

render(){
  let event1 = "string";
  let event2 = "string";
  let event3 = "string";
  let receptacleEvent = [];
  document.onkeydown = event => {
  return (
    receptacleEvent.push(event.key)
    if (receptacle.toString().indexOf(event1) >=0){
      this.handleOpen()
      return <Component1 open={this.state.open} close={this.handleClose.bind(this) />
    }
    if (receptacle.toString().indexOf(event2) >=0){
      this.handleOpen()
      return <Component2 open={this.state.open} close={this.handleClose.bind(this) />
    }
    if (receptacle.toString().indexOf(event3) >=0){
      this.handleOpen()
      return <Component3 open={this.state.open} close={this.handleClose.bind(this) />
    }
   )
  }
 }
}
```

I think I would like something like this

Comment: You want to pass one state to three different components with the handler to change it and when one of them changes the state you want it to change only for that one, is this correct ?

Comment: What's this? document.onkeydown = event => { ... } Your render method doesn't return anything.

Comment: this.handleOpen() - never change state in render method

Answer (score 0):

not possible, it is like I wanted to have 2 body but only one mind...

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31100620)